# How do I calculate the limit of this integral from n to n+2?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits

I need to find the limit, as $n\to\infty$ of $\int_n^{n+2}e^{-x^3}dx$. I tried taking the integral using integration by parts but that doesn't work so now I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that for all $x$ in $[n,n+2]$, $e^{-(n+2)^3}\leq e^{-x^3}\leq e^{-n^3}$. Hence, $$2e^{-(n+2)^3}\leq\int_n^{n+2}e^{-x^3}dx\leq2e^{-n^3}$$

Can you conclude by applying Sandwich Theorem as $n\to\infty$?

FULL EXPLANATION:

For all $x\in[n,n+2]$ we have $$n\leq x\leq n+2$$ which implies $$-(n+2)^3\leq -x^3\leq -n^3\implies e^{-(n+2)^3}\leq e^{-x^3}\leq e^{-n^3}$$.

Now integrate three sides of this inequality from $n$ to $n+2$. Everything is non-negative here so integrals will not change the direction of inequality.

$$\int_n^{n+2}e^{-(n+2)^3}dx\leq \int_n^{n+2}e^{-x^3}dx\leq \int_n^{n2}e^{-n^3}dx$$
which gives, as $e^{-n^3}$ and $e^{-(n+2)^3}$ are constants,
$$e^{-(n+2)^3}(n+2-n)\leq \int_n^{n+2}e^{-x^3}dx\leq e^{-n^3}(n+2-n)$$

Now as $n\to\infty, e^{-n^3}\to0$ and $e^{-(n+2)^3}\to 0$. By applying Sandwich Theorem the result is immediate.

Comment: How do we know $e^{-(n+2)^3}≤e^{-x^3}$ and $e^{-x^3} ≤ e^{-n^3}$?

Comment: For any $x\in[n,n+2]$ we have $n\leq x\leq n+2\implies n^3\leq x^3\leq (n+2)^3\implies -(n+2)^3\leq -x^3\leq -n^3\implies e^{-(n+2)^3}\leq e^{-x^3}\leq e^{-n^3}$.

Comment: And then why do we multiply by 2 when comparing those values to the integral?

Comment: I think you should think on this a bit more.. Once yo figure it out you will smile. Hint: Monotonicity property of integrals: if $f\leq g$ then $\int f\leq\int g$

Answer (score 2):

By integral mean value theorem:

$$\exists\ \xi_n\in(n,n+2)\text{ such that }\int_n^{n+2}e^{-x^3}\,dx=(n+2-n)e^{-\xi_n^3}=2e^{-\xi_n^3}$$

But $0\le e^{-\xi_n^3}\le e^{-n^3}\rightarrow_n0$

Therefore $\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\int_n^{n+2}e^{-x^3}\,dx=0$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

- Write your integral as $F(n+2)-F(n)$ (I'll let you guess what a good $F$ is)
- Note that a certain function is integrable over $(0,+\infty)$ ; what does that mean for $F$?
- Conclude